# Does "That {thing / one} I don't know" sound natural?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, conversation

I know that some people use this when they want to say that they have no idea about ***that particular thing***. But the thing is that, in my case none of them are native English speakers. So I thought it's worth to ask if natives use **That thing I don't know.** Though, indeed, it sounds OK and some natives even use "That I don't know" in the same context.

Also, what about **That *one* I don't know**? Sounds like native English to my non-native ears :)

- **That *one* I don't know.**
- **That *thing* I don't know.**

*Not (really) sure about that (one). I don't (really) know about that. Can't say about that (one)* - are among those I've heard from natives.

...a helpful reference I found on this. Still I think the question is valid.
[Should I say "I don't know" or "That I don't know"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/is-that-i-dont-know-correct-in-a-conversation/3153#3153)

Comment: I've heard "That one I don't know" often enough. Every time I've heard it, it follows [a series of known "ones", for contrast](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3287/16354). But "That thing I don't know" is awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if they 'sounded native' so I am contributing my **opinion**;

Those two sentences do not sound native to my native ears.  The only exception I could think of would be if you wanted to declare a few objects before stating to which category they belonged (i.e.: 'like' vs 'dislike').  You could say;

> *That one, that one,... and that one I like, that one and that
>   one I dislike*

But using a single item, it doesn't sound native to me.  The only time I have heard that kind of wording (and those specific sentences in particular) was from non-native people.

As far as those sentences being 'properly acceptable', I don't think so - but that's not what you asked.